# Using Ctrl+Shift+Alt in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use AutoHotKey to control my media. I have the following set which does not work:

```
;--- Ctrl+Shift+Alt to play/pause media ---
^+!::Send {Media_Play_Pause}`
```

The following does work:

```
;--- Ctrl+Shift+NumPad Divide to play/pause media ---
^+NumpadDiv::Send {Media_Play_Pause}`
```

Is there a way to make the Ctrl+Shift+Alt key binding work to play/pause media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
^+Alt::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
```

but this requires you to first hold down Control and Shift before pressing Alt.

However, we can mimic this mapping for all 3 potential final keys and we should be fine

---

Code:

```
^+Alt::
^!Shift::
+!Control::
Send {Media_Play_Pause}
return
```

Comment: Might need to send Up / Down events for each of the modifiers in that send command depending on the program receiving the input.

Comment: I just made this with the assumption that OP was likely going to use the `Pause/ Play` button in the Windows Global Context. If this is the case, it shouldn't really matter which program it affects since the OS will be handling actually sending the message to the program, which appears to be working properly from my side.